# Filter hash of hashes array to get only certain key & values

Tags: ruby, hash, filter, hash-of-hashes

Using [psd.rb gem](https://github.com/layervault/psd.rb) to return a [hash of the properties](https://gist.github.com/samjbmason/6129895) of a psd file. However I would like to somehow filter the results down just to the font name. Is there a method that can get the value of keys nested within a certain hash e.g the :font hash.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'json'

# h = <paste object from your gist here, and remove any characters that cause ruby to error>
             
def key_occurences(obj, k)

  # deal with arrays recursively
  return obj.map {|x| key_occurences(x,k) } if obj.is_a?(Array)

  # otherwise assume we have a Hash
  obj.to_a.map do |x|
    return x[1] if x[0] == k
    return key_occurences(x[1], k) if x[1].is_a?(Array) || x[1].is_a?(Hash) #recurse again if our key is itself a Hash or Array
  end.compact
end

puts key_occurences(h, :font).to_json
```

Your output will be:

```
[[{"name":"Georgia","sizes":[16.0],"colors":[[255,102,102,102]],"css":"font-family: \"Georgia\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 16.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(102, 102, 102, 255);"},{"name":"AntennaCond-Black","sizes":[16.0],"colors":[[255,89,89,87]],"css":"font-family: \"AntennaCond-Black\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 16.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(89, 89, 87, 255);"},[],[],[],[],[],[],{"name":"ArialMT","sizes":[15.0],"colors":[[255,51,51,51]],"css":"font-family: \"ArialMT\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 15.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(51, 51, 51, 255);"},{"name":"Georgia","sizes":[19.0],"colors":[[255,167,148,72]],"css":"font-family: \"Georgia\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 19.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(167, 148, 72, 255);"},[],[],[]],[[{"name":"MyriadPro-Regular","sizes":[65.0],"colors":[[255,255,255,255]],"css":"font-family: \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 65.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);"},{"name":"ArialMT","sizes":[14.0],"colors":[[255,255,255,255]],"css":"font-family: \"ArialMT\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 14.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);"},{"name":"Georgia","sizes":[18.0],"colors":[[255,255,255,255]],"css":"font-family: \"Georgia\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 18.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);"},[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],{"name":"AntennaCond-Black","sizes":[18.0,25.0],"colors":[[255,89,89,87]],"css":"font-family: \"AntennaCond-Black\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 18.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(89, 89, 87, 255);"},{"name":"AntennaCond-Black","sizes":[28.0],"colors":[[255,229,42,49]],"css":"font-family: \"AntennaCond-Black\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 28.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(229, 42, 49, 255);"},{"name":"AntennaCond-Black","sizes":[28.0],"colors":[[255,255,255,255]],"css":"font-family: \"AntennaCond-Black\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 28.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);"},[],{"name":"AntennaCond-Black","sizes":[28.0],"colors":[[255,255,255,255]],"css":"font-family: \"AntennaCond-Black\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 28.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);"},{"name":"AntennaCond-Black","sizes":[15.0],"colors":[[255,229,42,49]],"css":"font-family: \"AntennaCond-Black\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 15.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(229, 42, 49, 255);"},[],{"name":"AntennaCond-Black","sizes":[24.0,39.0],"colors":[[255,255,255,255]],"css":"font-family: \"AntennaCond-Black\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 24.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);"},[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],{"name":"Georgia","sizes":[18.0,16.0],"colors":[[255,165,146,70],[255,102,102,102]],"css":"font-family: \"Georgia\", \"Georgia-Italic\", \"MyriadPro-Regular\", \"AdobeInvisFont\";\nfont-size: 18.0pt;\ncolor: rgba(165, 146, 70, 255);"},[],[],[],[],[],[]]],[]]
```

And you can now further process that for the specific font info you want

### EDIT:

Per our comments dicussion, try:

```
def unwrap(arr)
  return arr if arr[0].is_a?(Hash)
  return nil if arr.is_a?(Array) && arr.size == 0
  unwrap(arr[0])
end

answer = key_occurences(h, :font).map! do |x| 
  unwrap(x)
end.compact!.flatten!

puts answer.map {|x| x[:name]}.uniq
```

which outputs:

```
Georgia
AntennaCond-Black
ArialMT
MyriadPro-Regular
```

Comment: Thanks so much I have manged to return it as a hash but then if i try and access one of the propeties like so `@fontHash = key_occurences(@psdHash, :font)
@singleFont = @fontHash[:name]` it throws an error saying no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer at the the second line

Comment: What are you attempting to do?  Look up a font by it's name, like "Georgia"?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes that is correct but I wanted to to get a list of all of them not just the first or second etc.

Comment: @SamMason, Sorry it's still not clear to me what you want.  If you are looking up a font by name, there would be one result.  Do you just want a list of all font names?  Please specify the exact output you are trying to achieve.  At this point it should be trivial to produce it.

Comment: As you can see from the json that is returned there are multiple name keys each with different values. I was hoping to get all the name keys values and print each one out separately. The info is all there in that json but I can't figure out how to get at the name keys values